# How to load react component dynamically using require with babel-register

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, react-dom-server, babel-register

I am using babel-register to use ES6 classes in node environment and want to load and render React component dynamically using require(**file_path**) with ReactDomServer, but its showing me following error:

"Invariant Violation: renderToStaticMarkup(): You must pass a valid ReactElement."

```
// enable es6
require('babel-register')({
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
    "extensions": [".jsx", ".js"]
});

// load component
var testComponent = require(testComponentPath);

console.log(testComponent); // { default: [Function: TestComponent] }

var html = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(testComponent);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your require statement to `var testComponent = require(testComponentPath).default;`, assuming the component is exported as default.

Comment: This is outdated and will no longer work. For it to work, you need to hardcode the path: require("your_file.js").default